# WordPress live search and filter custom fields

Tags: wp-query, ajax, jquery

I have the following code intended to fetch, filter and display custom post on input(onkeyup). However, it sin't working at the moment; I also get a 500 (Internal Server Error) when I open the console. What am I missing?

The PHP:`
         add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
         add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
         function data_fetch(){

```
   $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 6, 's' => esc_attr( 
  $_POST['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'custom_post' ) );
  if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); ?>
  <div class="cell s_result_box">
            <div class="title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php 
             the_title();?></a></li></div>

            <div class="content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
            <div class="meta"><span class=""><?php the_post_meta() ?></span> - <span 
            class=""><?php get_the_date(); ?></span></div>
            <div class="dividerline"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
       <?php endwhile; ?>

   add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_fetch' );
   function ajax_fetch() {
   ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
function fetchResults() {
    var keyword = jQuery('#searchInput').val();
    if(keyword == "" || keyword == 0){
        jQuery('#datafetch').html( " " );
        jQuery("#search-message").fadeIn();
        return;
    } else {
        jQuery("#search-message").fadeOut();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            type: 'post',
            data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: keyword  },
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
            }
        });
    }

}
</script>

      //The search form and results div
      <form class="t_margin_0" autocomplete="off">
              <input type="search" name="s" class="t_margin_0 dir_search" 
        placeholder="Search by name, location, department…" id="searchInput" 
        onkeyup="fetchResults()">
            </form>

     <div class="grid-x" id="datafetch"></div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

The 500 error means your ajax url is not working. 
Try using an external js file and [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

[More info in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: Apart from the 500 server error, the whole code doesn't work... still can't figure out why.

Comment: It won't work unless you solve the ajax 500 error.  Then debug the rest of your code if necessary.